# Precise & Stable current source (LED Driver)

Tags: current-source

I have a circuit to drive a string of series LEDs and currently we use a MCU generating a PWM signal which is adjusted to a BCR421 and then to the LEDs.

I was wondering if I could use the MCU output straight to my own current source circuit and then to the LEDs (thus eliminating all the components between the MCU and the BCR421). Generally those ICs have more stability and regulations then simple circuits so I don't know much less stable the circuit would be. For example using this one:

[image]

So it's suppose to work as a current source and have some kind of temperature regulation. However, using this kind of solution, would I still be missing other important characteristics from the BCR421? As my objective is to drive the LED, I need some current around 65mA that remains stable even with temperature changes.

In short, is it worth to make your own circuit or just take an IC instead?

**UPDATE:**

1) Why there's extra components between the MCU and the BCR? 
Apparently the other designer said the MCU output was not strong enough in harsh environments as there's a few long lines (from 5 to 130cm) from the MCU to multiple BCR's (about 5 to 15 BCR's for each MCU).

2) I'm designing a product which is a lamp. It's probably going to be used in normal situations like homes and offices. The temperature is probably gonna range between ambient temperature to 70~80C.

3) The stability is needed only to guarantee a specific forward current in the LED's to keep the light quality/color very much stable (around 65mA for the LED we have now, for example)

Comment: What are all the components between the MCU and BCR421? From the datasheet of the BCR421 (thanks for linking that in - not) you don't need any components for PWM dimming.

Comment: Felipe, are you designing a product? Making a one-off device? Are you educating yourself about LEDs & LED drive methods? What's your perspective here? You are asking a very general question, but looking for a specific answer.

Comment: Exactly what temperature stability do you need? Over what range of temperatures?  Why do you need that stability?

Comment: I updated the infos that you guys commented, thank you!